# How to use CGI to Determine if URL Request is using HTTPS?

Tags: coldfusion, cgi

I am trying to switch our site from HTTP to HTTPS. In some scenarios, we need the site to use HTTP and at other times, HTTPS. I inted to use CGI to determine whether the request is HTTP or HTTPS.

As far as I can tell, the JSON requests must match the original protocol request. If you request, HTTP:// example.org you must call JSON with HTTP:// example.org /file.JSON. If you request, HTTPS:// example.org/ you must call JSON with HTTPS:// example.org/file.JSON.

Normally, I would use CGI variables to tell me whether the request is HTTP or HTTPS. I can test for CGI.HTTPS to see if it is on or off. I can check CGI.SERVER_PORT too see if it is 80 or 443. I can check CGI.SERVER_PORT_SECURE to see if it is 0 or 1.

When I view our web site in every browser, I can dump the CGI variables and get what I expect 100% of the time.

When a few other people in our office and outside our office make the same request, they get CGI variable values that suggest their request is NOT secure. CGI.HTTPS will show off. CGI.SERVER_PORT will show 40. CGI.SERVER_PORT_SECURE will show 0. Every other indicator will show that the site is secure in every browser, but the CGI variable values say it's not secure.

The site behaves flawlessly 100% for everyone for dev and stage. Only in live, which is behind a load balancer, does this issue exist (for some people).

Is this a load balancer issue? Is this certificate settings issue? Why are my CGI variables lying to me? How can I work around this issue?

Comment: _Is this a load balancer issue?_ Not really an issue but my guess is it's how you have your load balancer configured. One of the many things you can do with a load balancer is have it support the TLS connections for you. When you configure a load balancer this way the TLS connection is terminated at the load balancer. So it is HTTPS from the client to your load balancer, but it is HTTP (non TLS) behind the load balancer to your servers. Since ColdFusion is running on your server it only sees the traffic as HTTP. You should never mix HTTPS and HTTP. AFAIK modern browsers won't even allow it

Comment: Actually, this is totally a load balancer issue. We removed the load balancer from the equation and it works perfectly. Yes, the problem is in how the load balancer is configured.

Comment: Protocol relative URL `// example.org/file.JSON` can come in handy in these cases